# Building a mask from a set of segment ranges

Tags: python, performance, numpy, bitmask

I'm working with data that consists of long sequences (the entire human genome, so total sequence length ~3e9). I have 22 files, each containing a sub-sequence between 5e7 and 2.5e8 characters.

For the purpose of my problem, those characters are either `0` or `1`, so the files look like this:

`010111101011001001000001100111100011110000110100001011000010`

The index of a given `0` or `1` is its "position" (0-based).

I have a set of non-overlapping ranges representing positions corresponding to the positions in the sequence files, e.g.

`[(1700, 2000), (9000, 15000), (16000, 18000)]`

For every position in the list of ranges, I would like to convert any `1` to `0` in the sequence (conversions are non-inclusive of upper range limit, like a python slice, see example).

Example:

```
sequence = 1111011101
ranges   = [(0, 3), (7,10)]
result   = 0001011000  
# the first 3 and last 3 positions are converted to 0 if they are not 
# 0 already, otherwise they are left alone
```

I am looking for an efficient way to update sequences given a set of ranges, possibly many times. I would potentially be doing this over and over, so I am concerned with speed. Memory is not a problem, so creating a mask from the ranges that is the same length as the sequence would be fine, as long as creating the mask is fast.

Comment: Load the whole thing into memory with numpy bytes array, create byte masks with `numpy.zeros` and add `ones` at the edges to pad, then just and it within numpy. Any problem with this?

Comment: This seems like a good algorithm to do on a graphics card - consider looking into PyCUDA. That may work well, or you may be slowed down by data transfer. As a possible solution to that, you can compress your data by a factor of eight by actually storing each set of 8 `1`s and `0`s in a byte. That will almost definitely speed up your algorithm considerably.

Comment: One interesting phenomenon is that, as long as your ranges *all* convert to zero or *all* convert to one at any time, it's perfectly okay if the ranges overlap - the data will just be written twice.

Comment: @lolopop No problem with this, I had something similar in mind. I was just wondering if there was some arcane high powered way of handling the ranges that bypassed the for-loop ;)

Comment: @IanPudney yes thats right, which is handy because sometimes the ranges actually do overlap, although usually I pre-process them by either merging or selecting by some criteria.

Comment: Would you be using the same `ranges` across all 22 files?

Comment: @Divakar no the ranges are distinct for a given file. The ranges are segments of the DNA sequences with a given function so they are specific to the sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the sequence represented? Surely not an integer as here (what of leading zeros?). Is it a string of digit characters? Or is it an ndarray of integers?

Assuming it is an integer array, there's nothing wrong with a simple for loop.

```
In [50]: sequence = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])

In [51]: ranges   = [(0, 3), (7,10)]

In [52]: for r in ranges:
   ....:     sequence[r[0]:r[1]] = 0
   ....:     

In [53]: sequence
Out[53]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

The vectorized and broadcasted operation of just setting the whole slice to zero will almost always be faster than anything with checks if an entry is zero first.

If the number of ranges is very large, the Python loop may be slow, in which case you can trivially move this to Cython, or consider concurrent access to a shared memory array with a Cython typed memory view, especially if you can guarantee that the ranges can never overlap.

If you start with a Python string, you could consider pre-computing an array format for it, for example using `numpy.char.array`. By default these arrays are immutable, like Python strings, but you can set the `write` flag to `True` for mutating them. If space is an issue due to data sequence sizes, you could go further and pre-compute your data as arrays of a custom 1-bit integer type, but don't do this optimization unless some benchmarks suggest you really need to.

Assuming you can convert to the standard length-1 string type in NumPy, this also works:

```
In [69]: s2 = np.char.array("1111011101", itemsize=1)    

In [70]: s2.setflags(write=True)

In [71]: for r in ranges:
    s2[r[0]:r[1]] = '0'
   ....:     

In [72]: s2
Out[72]: 
chararray(['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0'], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [73]: s2.tostring()
Out[73]: '0001011000'
```

Comment: Actually I just checked and the set of ranges contains 389222 pairs of values, which is not too bad. It would probably cap at 1M under different circumstances. The sequence representation is somewhat arbitrary. In reality the sequence consists of DNA bases i.e. `ACGT` but I am using 1 and 0 for different manipulations of mask files because the conditions I am masking out are always either true or false.

Comment: I added a bit in case you end up working with this data in bitstring format.